# Overcoming non standard drawer pull (handle) sizes

Tags: cabinets, hardware, drawers

Every drawer pull in my kitchen is 2-7/8" hole center which is certainly not a common size. I found some 3" that I like (thinking mine were actually 3" center) but unfortunately (and ever so obviously) they do not fit. I can't find any handles online in my current size so I'd like to change my cabinets to 3".  The obvious issue with that is that I will have visible holes in my cabinets because the new handles won't cover it up all the way. Is the any inventive way that I can overcome this issue without unnecessarily replacing my cabinet doors?  Also, I'm open to keeping my existing non standard size if I can actually find some.  Right now that seems impossible though.

[image: handle]

Comment: Handle sizes aren't especially standardized. You may be able to find some new handles that either are the same distance between holes, or where the new handle at least covers the old hole. Go to a kitchen hardware showroom and look around, there are zillions of options for cabinet hardware and the big box stores only tend to have a dozen. A cabinet hardware specialist can have hundreds more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use color matched wood putty to fill the holes. They'll mostly by hidden by the handles, so it may not look as bad as you'd think.

[Minwax Colored Wood Putty](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Minwax-3-75-oz-Golden-Oak-Wood-Putty-13611/100376127)

Comment: I don't know if the linked product was simply an example, but I should note that it is a "non-hardening" putty. While these have their place, I'd avoid using them on kitchen cabs because dirt/grease can build up on them and darken over time. So what started as a fabulous fix can look terrible in a relatively short time.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate You're right, good point. Maybe a stainable wood filler that hardens would be better.